# Drupal | Barcode Module remove bottom text

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, barcode

I am using Barcode module to generate a barcode image from Drupal 7. Here is the link of module https://drupal.org/project/barcode. There is a key printed at the bottom of the barcode image file. I want to remove that key and just show the barcode. Is there anyway to do it with this module.

Answer (score 0):

your request is a little generic because you have to comment all lines regarding @imagettftext inside the plugins that you want to use.

files .inc for every type of barcodes are present under folder plugins/ of the module.